# Сохранить Data Template для строки / ячейки DataGrid при прокрутке вручную вверх-вниз

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Есть DataGrid заданный следующим образом:

```
<DataGrid
    Name="DataGrid1"
    Width="Auto"
    Height="Auto"
    Margin="0"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
    HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
    VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    Background="White"
    BorderBrush="DimGray"
    BorderThickness="2"
    CanUserReorderColumns="False"
    ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource CommonColumnHeaderStyle}"
    CurrentCellChanged="AllChannelsDataGrid_CurrentCellChanged"
    DataContext="{Binding Source={x:Static localClasses:ChannelsMonitor.Instance}}"
    EnableRowVirtualization="True"
    FrozenColumnCount="0"
    HorizontalGridLinesBrush="Black"
    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
    IsReadOnly="True"
    LayoutUpdated="DataGrid1_LayoutUpdated"
    Loaded="DataGrid1_Loaded"
    LoadingRow="DataGrid1_LoadingRow"
    MaxColumnWidth="200"
    RowHeaderWidth="0"
    RowHeight="40"
    SelectionMode="Single"
    SelectionUnit="Cell"
    SizeChanged="DataGrid1_SizeChanged"
    Unloaded="DataGrid1_Unloaded"
    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=ChannelState, Converter={StaticResource ChannelStateBrushConverter}}" />
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn
            Width="45"
            MinWidth="40"
            MaxWidth="100"
            CanUserReorder="False"
            CanUserResize="False"
            CanUserSort="False"
            CellStyle="{StaticResource ChannelNumberCellStyle}"
            Header="№"
            SortDirection="Ascending"
            SortMemberPath="ChannelNumber" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn
            x:Name="allChannelsDataGridName"
            Width="250*"
            MinWidth="220"
            MaxWidth="400"
            CanUserResize="True"
            CanUserSort="False"
            CellStyle="{StaticResource ChannelNameCellStyle}"
            Header="Наименование"
            SortMemberPath="ChannelName" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn
            Width="135"
            MinWidth="110"
            MaxWidth="300"
            CanUserReorder="False"
            CanUserResize="False"
            CanUserSort="False"
            CellStyle="{StaticResource ChannelStateCellStyle}"
            Header="Столбец 3" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn
            Width="280*"
            MinWidth="160"
            MaxWidth="300"
            CanUserReorder="False"
            CanUserResize="True"
            CanUserSort="False"
            CellStyle="{StaticResource ChannelInputLevelCellStyle}"
            Header="Столбец 4" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn
            Width="85"
            MinWidth="50"
            MaxWidth="150"
            CanUserReorder="False"
            CanUserResize="False"
            CanUserSort="False"
            CellStyle="{StaticResource ChannelAmpCellStyle}"
            Header="Столбец 5" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn
            Width="95"
            MinWidth="50"
            MaxWidth="300"
            CanUserReorder="False"
            CanUserResize="False"
            CanUserSort="False"
            CellStyle="{StaticResource ChannelPriorityCellStyle}"
            Header="Столбец 6" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn
            Width="100"
            MinWidth="50"
            MaxWidth="300"
            CanUserReorder="False"
            CanUserResize="False"
            CanUserSort="False"
            CellStyle="{StaticResource ChannelCutLevelCellStyle}"
            Header="Столбец 7" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn
            Width="120"
            MinWidth="50"
            MaxWidth="400"
            CanUserReorder="False"
            CanUserResize="False"
            CanUserSort="False"
            CellStyle="{StaticResource AllConferenceCBCellStyle}"
            Header="Столбец 8" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn
            x:Name="allChannelsDataGridComment"
            Width="*"
            MinWidth="100"
            MaxWidth="Infinity"
            CanUserResize="True"
            CanUserSort="False"
            CellStyle="{StaticResource ChannelCommentCellStyle}"
            Header="Столбец 9" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
```

Для крайнего левого столбца стиль и дата темплейт:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="Template_normal">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            FontSize="23"
            FontWeight="Bold"
            Text="{Binding Path=ChannelNumber, Converter={StaticResource ChannelNumberInDataConverter}, Mode=OneWay}" />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="Template_selected">
    <Grid>
        <Ellipse
            Name="Circle"
            Width="39"
            Height="38"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Fill="Transparent"
            Stroke="Crimson"
            StrokeThickness="3" />
        <TextBlock
            Name="channelNumberTextBlock"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            FontSize="20"
            FontWeight="Bold"
            Foreground="Crimson"
            Text="{Binding Path=ChannelNumber, Converter={StaticResource ChannelNumberInDataConverter}, Mode=OneWay}" />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

.............

```
<Style x:Key="NumberCellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource Template_normal}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0.4" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource Template_selected}" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

При клике на эту ячейку применяется шаблон Template_selected, но при прокрутке вручную через скроллбар опять возвращается Template_normal. Как его сохранить при прокрутке?

Comment: Добавить свойство IsSelected к самой модели и при клике выставлять его и смотреть триггером на него

Comment: @vitidev: Хм, а когда присваивать IsSelected = false?

Comment: @VladD Зависит же от задачи. Можно по еще одному клику инвертировать свойство IsSelected у модели.

Comment: я понял задачу так - нужно сохранить выделение, чтобы оно не снималось. Может я неверно понимаю проблему.

Comment: @vitidev: Мне показалось, что нужно просто, чтобы шаблон не менялся при временной потере фокуса. (Судя по всему, при клике по скроллбару фокус уходит.)

Comment: Да, нужно сохранить выделение, чтобы оно не снималось, когда ячейка уходит за область видимости. Я пробовал IsSelected = true, выставлять в обработчике LoadingDataRow, но это оказалось ненадежно. В ячейке содержится некий номер, я его беру сравниваю с запомненным и выделяю ячейку. Но при прокрутке часто выделяется не та ячейка что надо